# Why is Bluetooth PAN functioning slowly on one machine but fine on another?

Tags: windows-7, internet, bluetooth, pan

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit and the Bluetooth dongle which I use to connect to the Internet via Bluetooth PAN (Personal Area Network) is only functioning at 12% of what it should be according to task manager.

It performs much better on another computer I have. I have installed all the necessary drivers and it still is being slow. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was also because of intermittent bluetooth connection. The severely slow and unreliable data transfer rates were caused because of lack of computer performance, I added more ram and it was back up at 100% data transfer rate.